# How do I install a text-only Ubuntu server like I have had for years?

Tags: server, command-line

It seems to be a regression in 11.10 that I cannot install just a text-based server from the alternate media, there is no option visible in the installation, and no way to even turn it off that I can see. I don't have a graphics card or monitor that work reasonably in graphical mode for most servers I run, because it is useless, unattended, consumes memory and other resources, etc.

Comment: Download the Ubuntu Server ISO... http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate Desktop and Server version now. The [Server install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download) does not come with anything graphical and also includes some nice server features, like load overview when you log into ssh.